# Homogeneous equation3

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

*Please help me to solve this question. Thanks*

Question:

> resolvent Homogeneous equation $=> (y+\sqrt {x^2+y^2})dx-xdy$

My Attempt:

$u=\frac{y}{x}\  =>  y ′=u ′x+u$

dy=udx+xdu

$(y+\sqrt {x^2+y^2})dx-x(udx+xdu)=0$

Honestly, I don't know how to continue from here.

Comment: Welcom! ${}{}{}{}$

Comment: @amWhy ;))))) thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put $y=ux$ which gives $$(ux+\sqrt{x^2+u^2x^2})dx-x(udx+xdu)=0$$ $$\implies x\sqrt{1+u^2}dx=x^2du$$ $$\implies\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{\sqrt{1+u^2}}$$

Now, this is variable separable form and i guess you know how to solve it further.

Comment: yes.Excellent. Thank you for your answer ;)